# R - Removing corpus wordset from larger corpus to find unique words

Tags: r, corpus, text-analysis, word-cloud

I have two corpuses (which I turn into DocumentTermMatrices, data frames, and then wordclouds) of which, one is a subset of another. To be exact, one is a corpus of text regarding just one university and the other is the corpus of text regarding all the universities in that conference.

Is there a way in R to extract just the words unique to the smaller wordset? This is kind of what I've been running so far for each corpus (this is for the 'conference' corpus)

```
> SECDraft = read.csv("SECDraftScouting.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
> SECcorpus = Corpus(VectorSource(SECDraft$Report))
> SECcorpus = tm_map(SECcorpus, tolower)
> SECcorpus = tm_map(SECcorpus, PlainTextDocument)
> SECcorpus = tm_map(SECcorpus, removePunctuation)
> SECcorpus = tm_map(SECcorpus, removeWords, c("strengths", "weaknesses", "notes", stopwords("english")))
> SECfrequencies = DocumentTermMatrix(SECcorpus)
> SECallReports = as.data.frame(as.matrix(SECfrequencies))
> wordcloud(colnames(SECallReports), colSums(SECallReports), random.order = FALSE, max.words = 200, scale=c(2, 0.25))
```

thanks guys!

Comment: You can specify a dictionary of words to extract within `DocumentTermMatrix`, see `?termFreq`.

Comment: @lukeA would that pull a corpus of words unique to just 1 school though? from my reading of the dictionary parameter, won't that just result in a corpus of words that are shared between both corpuses (conference and school)? for instance, it would most certainly include the word 'good' after that parameter, but that wouldn't be a word unique to that school).

Answer (score 1):

As in my response to your other post, I would do this in the [`quanteda` package](http://github.com/kbenoit/quanteda).  I'm not able to test this because I do not have your .csv files, but this ought to work:

```
# install.packages(quanteda)
require(quanteda)

# read in each corpus separately, directly into quanteda
mycorpus1 <- corpus(textfile("UKDraftScouting.csv", textField = "report"))
mycorpus2 <- corpus(textfile("SECMinusUKDraftScouting.csv", textField = "report"))
# assign docset variables to each corpus as appropriate 
docvars(mycorpus1, "docset") <- 1 
docvars(mycorpus2, "docset") <- 2
myCombinedCorpus <- mycorpus1 + mycorpus2

myDfm <- dfm(myCombinedCorpus, 
             groups = "docset", # by docset instead of document
             ignoredFeatures = c("strengths", "weaknesses", "notes", stopwords("english"))),
             matrixType = "dense")

# create a logical vector indexing the features unique to corpus 1
uniqueToCorpus1 <- (myDfm[1, ] & !myDfm[2, ])
# this is the dfm with features unique to dfm1
myDfm[1, uniqueToCorpus1]
# list the word features as a character vector
features(myDfm[1, uniqueToCorpus1])
```